# Is there an easy way to background a sudo shell?

Tags: shell, sudo, background-process

A bit more details, what I'm looking for is some kind of `^Z` for `sudo` shells.

For instance when running a long command I can hit `^Z` to suspend the command or when I do `~^Z` in `ssh` after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then I can simply do `fg` and get my long command/`ssh` session running again.

Comment: Have you considered running the root shell in a `screen` or `tmux` session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `suspend` (as long as you invoked the shell with `sudo -s` instead of `sudo -i`):

```
anthony@Haruhi:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for anthony: 
root@Haruhi:~# suspend

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo -s
anthony@Haruhi:~$
```

If you invoked it with `sudo -i`, you can use `suspend -f` to force it to suspend anyway; note that you need to be careful there (as if you did that to an *actual* login shell, it could be pretty difficult to resume it).

Comment: Awesome, I always use `-s` so I should be fine. Thanks!